# Fancybox links show different symbols instead a picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to make simple image gallery, maybe somebody can give some advise. I use gem fancybox-rails.
When I'm pressing on image, I have differen symbols instead an image like this:

```
�PNG  IHDR��~J�sRGB���gAMA���a pHYs���+��IDATx^���-YY&�?��j�pr���з�������yp�����Qg0M�oEE����FI����{Ϲ'��s����O��}� t�3�����u�vժ�V��}ްj�*+VcPua�n?�`Y6R��_)DA+�2�i���K�"v�3��KY n|DQ�����p���΢�iaue �O����9��>h�� <�M۴M'��*�J�����3��C6��Q�|��%�{��~��;w��1�/cf���n#o���9�F@��H��>ff'p��b��9Z@z�Ē��[�a��y��<�����6m�6=�c˸�Q$� ����m��F����[J�����{�x����۴M��H��7��t����M_W :͘tcN���h�h���+��1���Y����`��߁���NHi)6 �3��v���`
```

I've installed fancybox like in [tutorial](https://github.com/chrismytton/fancybox-rails).

My view file is:

```
<div class="container" style="float: none">
    <div class="row" style="float: none">
        <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <%= link_to image_tag(picture.image.url),
                            picture.image.url,
                    class: "fancybox", rel: "gallery1" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

My application.js file hase next code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();

});
```

Thanks

Comment: can you try by changing the class name with something `grouped_elements` instead of `fancybox`

Comment: @Kh Ammad thanks, thsts helped!

Comment: I will add the answer as well so that people approch that will get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by changing the class name with something like `grouped_elements` instead of fancybox. Please follow this [link](http://blog.likewise.org/2013/07/adding-a-fancybox-gallery-to-a-rails-3-dot-2-app-in-5-steps/) to get more help.